# conda-store LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, conda, jupyterhub

I am trying to deploy a Docker image that will allow my current JupyterHub Docker image to connect to a shared conda store. My JupyterHub server is already LDAP authenticated and mounts the GPFS home properly but I am not sure how conda-store authentication can be linked to the JupyterHub server.